# Comparing new files and old files using Java

Tags: java, loops, compare

I've created a java program that will compare the two files wherein the two files consist of new files and old files. see below :

```
new files --> new.txt 
postgresql-contrib-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-devel-8.1.23-10.el5_10.i386.rpm
postgresql-devel-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-docs-8.1.23-10.el5_10.x86_64.rpm
postgresql-libs-8.1.23-10.el5_10.i386.rpm
tzdata-2014b-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
tzdata-java-2014b-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-demo-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-javadoc-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-manual-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-xsltc-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-server-sdk-1.1.1-48.101.el5_10.3.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-server-Xdmx-1.1.1-48.101.el5_10.3.x86_64.rpm
```

---

```
old files --> old.txt
xalan-j2-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-demo-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-javadoc-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-manual-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xalan-j2-xsltc-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-server-sdk-1.1.1-48.101.el5_10.3.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-server-Xdmx-1.1.1-48.101.el5_10.3.x86_64.rpm
```

For the given files above my question is how to compare it string by string which is the old and which are new and then remove the old version, replace it by the used of the new. It must be to remove all old  files and replace it by all new files.

sample code . it is just to compare not yet for getting and removing files for he updated one.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;


 public class Testing {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 BufferedReader bfr2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       System.in));
 String s1 = "";
 String  s3 = "";
 String y = "", z = "";

 File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\geno\\Desktop\\newfiles.txt");
 File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\geno\\Desktop\\oldfiles.txt");
// File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\geno\\Desktop\\changes.txt");
 //File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\geno\\Desktop\\copy.txt");

  BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
  BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

  while ((z = bfr1.readLine()) != null)
    s3 += z;

 while ((y = bfr.readLine()) != null)
    s1 += y;

 System.out.println();

  System.out.println(s3);

  if (s3.equals(s1)) {
   System.out.println("Content of both files are same");
  } else {

   System.out.println("Content of both files are not same");

 }

 }

}`
```

Comment: using [File#lastModified()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified())?

Comment: In approaching a problem like this, it's often helpful to think about what "algorithm" you would use if you were doing this in your head. How would you look at these two lists and decide which "files" in the old list have new versions and  thus need to be replaced? In other words, how do you know that `xalan-j2-javadoc-2.6.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm` and `xalan-j2-javadoc-2.7.0-6jpp.2.x86_64.rpm` are different versions of the same file? Figure out how you would do that "manually", and then figure out how to implement that algorithm in code.

Comment: @drewmoore - sorry to tell you that I am new in Java and I just only know bash scripting it is very challenging to me because I don't know the implementation in java .. Yeah I know to do it manually bay using bash commands but when we talk about java .. hands off

Comment: @ImmerAllein - how should I use that function ? can you give some example ?

Comment: @user3626800 can you post your attempted code first?